# html looks weird in outlook, but ok in browser

Tags: html, encoding, utf-8, outlook

I'm doing mailings, which contains html code.
If I check my HTML in IE or FF, everything looks great. But when I sent the mail, the characters become very weird:

In browser: Information générale
,In E-mail : Information g�n�rale

My HTML meta:  `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`

Clearly this has something to do with the encoding, but I don't get why it looks OK in a browser and not in the email...

I have other HTML emails (newsletters received from other persons) which use the same HTML meta, and those emails look just fine..

Comment: Look for the `Content-Type` header in the message source.

Comment: Hi ntrrgc, this is the Content-Type: multipart/alternative;

Comment: That's because you are sending a multipart message (one which contains e.g. both plain text and HTML). Each part has its own `Content-Type`. One of them should be something like `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`.

Answer (score 1):

� is an indication that the browser/E-Mail client uses UTF-8 to render the document, but encountered an invalid character from a different encoding.

It isn't enough to set the `content-type` meta tag; your *data* actually needs to match the encoding you're declaring.

If it comes from a file, make sure the file is encoded as UTF-8 (usually, the editor will offer you a setting in the "Save as...." dialog.)

If it comes from a database, see [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: Hi Pekka, thank you for your answer. My data comes indeed from a database. I will look into this.

Answer (score 0):

In the email you have one more place to add an encoding:
 - The mail header
 - the mine header
 - if content is text/HTML in the HTML header

All of these need to be set right.

Sorry for short answer. Writing this on my cellphone.